# How can I include a jar file in a distinct package when deploying

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, ant, build

I have an ant script that I use to build my J2EE application and create jar files. The problem is the following: Two jar files are necessary for the application to run.

```
commons-math-2.0.jar
commons-math-1.0.jar
```

However, I want to only use the 2.0 for a particular package inside the application with the rest of the application using 1.0. How can I build the application to only use the 2.0 version for example with a package name such as com.naurus.eventhandler.risk? Again, I'm using an Ant script, but if there's an easier way to do this sort of thing I'm willing to experiment. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If the two jars contain different classes/packages there should be no problem to have all of them in the application classpath. It is then a matter of discipline not to use the classes from the one jar in the other package.

However I guess these two jars contain mostly the same classes/methods? There are many ways of using different versions of the same classes:

- Using different `ClassLoader` instances. I would not qualify it as "easy", far from it means opening the door to a bunch of nasty bugs. (can be helped using a tool like OSGi)
- Splitting the application in two processes, these process being launched in the same Ant target and using any mean (CORBA, RMI, REST, etc.) to communicate.

I would not advise using any of these methods though. **It would probably be simpler to make all your packages use the same version.** Is there any specific difficulty in doing so?

Answer (score 0):

That will be problematic since both JAR files will end up in the same classpath when you deploy your J2EE application.  You could achieve what you are trying to attempt with [OSGI bundles](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2008/jw-03-osgi1.html), which allow each package to have separate dependencies.  However, that is a relatively large refactoring of your application.

IMO, it would be best to either:

a)  Duplicate the features you need from 2.0 (if the number is small and the license allows it, e.g., package individual classes).

or

b)  Spend the time to upgrade the entire application to 2.0

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a question though. It seems that commons-math is an apache jar file. Could it be possible that we combine both of them into one? Since there are some functions in 1.0 that are no longer present in 2.0 i.e. deprecated. That is the real cause of the issue...I'm not sure if taking those jars apart and building them into one would be "legal" though?

Comment: If they are deprecated, but still present, you can use them.  They just might go away in a future release.  I would recommend upgrading to 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the manisfest in your jar to define the classpath.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html

Although honestly it seems a bit convoluted, but it is your requirement.